# Query by Form for multiple fields in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to create a query which takes field parameters through a form. For this, I created a form with combo boxes and drop down options to select the values from, this populates a text value in the respective invisible text fields whose default value I have set to null. Now in my query I give criteria for column as iif(isNull([Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form]), [column_in_table], [Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form]). I have done this for all the columns on which the where clause comes from the form. I have tried running this. The results seem to be random. It worked for three columns, but when I played around with it, it was giving me empty result set. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or if there is a better way to implement query by form in Access.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the above solution, but I have created a workaround for it. I am creating a new column for every column in where clause and define it like this:
new_column: [field] = [Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form] or [Forms]![Conditions]![text_on_form] is null

This seems to solve the problem, but I would like to know why the previous method was not working. And also I would like to know how I can compare check boxes from the form with yes/no columns in the table using the second method. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create dynamic SQL.  Here is the method in vba I generally prefer:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT tblName.* From tblName WHERE (1=1)"

If Not IsNull(Me.combo1) Then
    SQL = SQL & " And ([Field1] Like ""*" & Me.combo1 & "*"")" ' I am using like statements here, but that is because this is a search tool.
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.combo2) Then
    SQL = SQL & " And ([Feild2] Like ""*" & Me.combo2 & "*"")"
End If

Docmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Basically, add on to the SQL statement only if the user has put a value into your text box/ combo box or whatever.  The "Where (1=1)" is to account for a situation where all fields are null.

Play with this concept to create your SQL statements.  Avoid using invisible text boxes to store data, it generally means you are doing something wrong and will get mixed results (someone else on this forum can explain better than me why that is).

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! I also have numerous text boxes in the form for the dynamic query. How do we match the form value and column values with text boxes using VB?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It might help if you describe what exactly your are trying to accomplish.  Are you using Access as a backend (does Access store your tables)?  Is your form bound to a table?  You will need to play with the code I provided, but generally, replace the "me.combo1" with your form value and "[Field1]" with your column header.

Comment: I am using Access as my backend.It is a flat table.The form that I am using to generate the query is not bound to any table.I am trying  to modify the query conditions but there is just too many problems.Problem with VB is,I don't understand VB.I am having a hard time trying to figure out what the code is doing.I need a code that can take text values from invi textboxes in the form which populate when values from drop down are selected.I also have yes or no fields and I am taking that through the form as checkboxes. Anyways,I'll be really grateful if you could help me code this dynamic query

Comment: In the VB code above, how does the code know which form to check for the null values with just 1=1? And I also don't understand the concept of "Me.". Sorry, but I am just a beginner. I want to learn all this

Comment: You do not need dynamic SQL, Access takes care of all that for you.  Visit this help article to get started: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/bind-a-blank-form-or-report-to-one-or-more-tables-or-queries-HP005188812.aspx

Comment: Also I would purchase a book to understand the fundamentals of Access.  You are trying to make a simple access task complicated by using VBA!  It will be helpful to first understand how Access works without having to use VBA.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Like operator. Put this in your criteria field in the query `Like "\*" & Forms![Form_Name]![Form_Field]  & "\*"` -- This tells it to get anything if the field is blank (or null) and matches whatever you have in the field. This may not be what you want. It should be noted that it will return anything with the text string in it. For example: if you type "the" it will return tether, these, theses, thermometer (anything with the word "the" in it. It works best for multi word or longer strings that can be matched more accurately, however it works for a search query because there is usually a set of human eyes looking for the result and erroneous results is not a huge problem.